# Hibernate/Spring boot jpa on Impala/kudu with cloudera jdbc driver

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, impala

I have an API in spring boot using hibernate.
Initially, the database to request was Hive, it's now Kudu throw Impala.

I followed recommendations and set the dialect to `org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect`.

The classical requests work fine excepting the `Page<T> findAll(@Nullable Specification<T> var1, Pageable var2)` from `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository`
when I paginate (page > 0) and so I have the exception:

> [Cloudera]ImpalaJDBCDriver ERROR processing query/statement. Error Code: 0, SQL state: TStatus(statusCode:ERROR_STATUS, sqlState:HY000, errorMessage:ParseException: Syntax error in line 1:
> select limit 10 10 qualityres0_.id ...
> ^
> Encountered: LIMIT
> Expected: ALL, CASE, CAST, DATE, DEFAULT, DISTINCT, EXISTS, FALSE, IF, INTERVAL, LEFT, NOT, NULL, REPLACE, RIGHT, STRAIGHT_JOIN, TRUNCATE, TRUE, IDENTIFIER

```
Spring boot version: 2.3.4.RELEASE
Impala jdbc driver:  com.cloudera.impala.jdbc ImpalaJDBC41 v2.6.15.1017
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally it works fine with org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect